# Facebook SDK Unity Invite

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm developping an android  game in witch  I connect to facebook . If the user is connected  , he can invite 5 of his facebook to the application.  I used this code. The problem that in the script InteractiveConsole.cs  I want when  the user click on button of invite  , he can invite only 5 of his friends, when he choose 5 friends ,  he can't invite more than 5.
Here is my code:

```
#region FB.AppRequest() Friend Selector

public string FriendSelectorTitle = "";
public string FriendSelectorMessage = "Derp";
public string FriendSelectorFilters = "[\"all\",\"app_users\",\"app_non_users\"]";
public string FriendSelectorData = "{}";
public string FriendSelectorExcludeIds = "";
public string FriendSelectorMax = "";

private void CallAppRequestAsFriendSelector()
{
    // If there's a Max Recipients specified, include it
    int? maxRecipients = null;
    if (FriendSelectorMax != "")
    {
        try
        {
            maxRecipients = Int32.Parse(FriendSelectorMax);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            status = e.Message;
        }
    }

    // include the exclude ids
    string[] excludeIds = (FriendSelectorExcludeIds == "") ? null : FriendSelectorExcludeIds.Split(',');

    FB.AppRequest(
        FriendSelectorMessage,
        null,
        FriendSelectorFilters,
        excludeIds,
        maxRecipients,
        FriendSelectorData,
        FriendSelectorTitle,
        Callback
    );
}
#endregion
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share with us the result you are getting? or the problem?

Comment: @Gaston Claret:Hi,the problem that i can select and invite more than 5 friends from my facebook friends. The problem that i want to select only 5 friends of my facebook list.

Comment: There might be a max cap of 5 friends on android for your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found out why it's not working.
First to limit the numbers of friends invited to 5 in my application , i should change this:

```
public string FriendSelectorMax = "5";
```

i cheked again the documententation and it say this.

"maxRecipients : Platform-dependent The maximum number of recipients the user should be able to choose in the platform multi-friend selector dialog. Only guaranteed to work in Unity Web Player applications."

Here is the link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Apprequest

the think is that maxRecipients is working in WebPlayer and not for android until now.

I tested the code in unity web player and i can invite only 5 friends and when i switch the platform to android, it's not working as they said in the documentation.